# Why last version of Android Studio wizard extends deprecated ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated, android-appcompat

I'm confused. I just updated the Android studio and the SDK. I created a new project using the wizard, adding an activity with navigation drawer and a fragment and the appcompat v7:22.1.1

Why it uses a deprecated `ActionBarActivity` extension of the main activity?

So, what's the best choiche to make an application that can run on Android 4.0.1 and later?

**EDIT:**
Trying to use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`. But whit the activity generated automtically from the Navigation Drawer Wizard option I get an error in runtime

> Error inflating class fragment...

Answer (score 3):

`ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated in favor of the new `AppCompatActivity`, you can simply use the Android Studio wizard and change from `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`

As you can see in [v7-appcompat source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.java) from version v22.1.0 `ActionBarActivity` simply extends `AppCompatActivity`:

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public class ActionBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

**EDIT:** To fix the error **"Error inflating class fragment"** you need to change `getActionBar()` inside `NavigationDrawerFragment` class like this:

```
private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}
```

Comment: Just tried, getting error:  Unable to start activity... Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: @Seraphim's I just updated my answer with the solution of "Error inflating class fragment" issue. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Looks pretty much like an issue in the Android Studio itself. I'd file bug if I were you.
Looks like from now on recommended kind of support activity with action bar features is [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html). If you develop for Android 4.0 and later you can stick to the `android.app.Activity`, but I don't recommend it because if some bug will be found in the support activity classes, it'll be fixed and added to support library, while in case of `android.app` activities you'll need to wait for device vendor to add these fixes in their update.